# 'Session' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have the following code, that uses session but i have an error in the line :

```
if (Session["ShoppingCart"] == null)
```

the error is `cS0103: The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context` what is the problem ?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.SessionState;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ShoppingCart
/// </summary>
public class ShoppingCart
{
    List<CartItem> list;
    public ShoppingCart()
    {
        if (Session["ShoppingCart"] == null)
            list = new List<CartItem>();
        else
            list = (List<CartItem>)Session["ShoppingCart"];
    }
}
```

Comment: which method ? do you mean a constructor ? in aonther class

Comment: You call it from a non session page - or from a thread.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue is that your class does not inherit from Page. you need to Change

```
public class ShoppingCart
```

to

```
public class ShoppingCart : Page
```

and it will work

Answer (score 47):

Use

```
if (HttpContext.Current == null || 
    HttpContext.Current.Session == null || 
    HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart"] == null)
```

instead of

```
if (Session["ShoppingCart"] == null)
```

Comment: But I get this exception System.NullReferenceException .. !!

Comment: Have you abanomed the session or some thing? my guess is that HttpContext.Current is null or HttpContext.Current.Session is null... but i have no idea why with so little info

Comment: this HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart"] was cool. thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

You either need to convert your class to a `Page` by inheriting from `Page`, or have the `Session` passed in, or use `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

Comment: But I get this exception System.NullReferenceException .. !!

Answer (score 0):

In my case only try-catch block fix problem, like this:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /// Using from Try-Catch to handle "Session state is not available in this context." error.
        try
        {
            //must incorporate error handling because this applies to a much wider range of pages 
            //let the system do the fallback to invariant 
            if (Session["_culture"] != null)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Session["_culture"].ToString());
                //it's safer to make sure you are feeding it a specific culture and avoid exceptions 
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Session["_culture"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use session directly then simply add the following namespace:

```
using system.web.mvc
```