# MVC Core:The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am receiving the following error, how would I resolve this in MVC ASP Core 2 ?

The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context.

```
 Session.Remove(_currentProductResult);
```

**Other Codes**

```
  Session[_currentProductResult] = currentProductResult;
```

**Error:**

```
The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context
```

Should I go with Version or something else in Intellisense? Sometimes Intellisense can be incorrect.

[image]

This resource is for older projects.

['Session' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969563/session-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: Use `HttpContext.Session`.

Comment: Or you can also use `HttpContext.Session.SetString("MyKey", "MyVal");`

Comment: You're right, Intellisense can be wrong sometimes, and it is in this case. Have you tried the solution you linked to in your question?

Comment: Hi Kirk, feel free to write in answer, and I can give points, thanks