# Net Core MVC: Name Session does not exist in Current Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-2.0

I am receiving an error in the last line.  How would I resolve this? Trying to convert Net 4.6.2 Project to MVC Net Core.

```
Last Line Error: Name Session does not exist in Current Context.

public class TransferPropertyOwnershipController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult GetNewOwnerRecord(int ownerID, int propertyID)
    {
        OwnerManager ownerManager = new OwnerManager();
        var newOwner = ownerManager.Get(ownerID, true);

        PropertyOwnerRoleViewModel newPropertyOwnerRoleViewModel = new PropertyOwnerRoleViewModel();
        newPropertyOwnerRoleViewModel.OwnerID = newOwner.OwnerID;
        newOwner.Address = new Model.Address();
        newPropertyOwnerRoleViewModel.Owner = newOwner;
        newPropertyOwnerRoleViewModel.IsPrimaryOwner = false;
        newPropertyOwnerRoleViewModel.OwnershipPercentage = 0;
        newPropertyOwnerRoleViewModel.PropertyID = propertyID;

        IQueryable<PropertyOwnerRoleViewModel> currentOwnersResult = Session[_currentOwnersResult] as IQueryable<PropertyOwnerRoleViewModel>;
```

**Proposed Solution:**

**Number 1**

```
HttpContext.Session.GetString(_currentOwnersResult]) 

Error Text: 'ISession' does not contain a definition for 'GetString' and no accessible extension method 'GetString' accepting a first argument of type 'ISession' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**Number 2**

```
IQueryable<PropertyOwnerRoleViewModel> currentOwnersResult = HttpContext.Current.Session(_currentOwnersResult]) as IQueryable<PropertyOwnerRoleViewModel>;

Error Text: 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no accessible extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**Resources:**

Trying to utilize this solution, but having issues.
['Session' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969563/session-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: More info on .NET Core MVC session [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [add service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#session-state) in your startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      ....
   services.AddSession(options =>
        {

        });
....
   }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
.....
        app.UseSession();
....
    }
```

Comment: nm comes from 'no ma'?