# The name Session does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, session, model-view-controller

I am trying to store a logged in user's information in a Session. However it does not seem to be working in my application. I keep getting the errors "The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context"

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult userLogin(User user)
    {
        using (TheDbContext db = new TheDbContext())
        {
            var usr = db.userAccount.Single(u => u.Email == user.Email && u.Password == user.Password);

            if (usr != null)
            {

                Session["UserID"] = usr.ID.ToString();
                Session["Email"] = usr.Email.ToString();

                return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
            }

        }
            return View();
    }
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Framework or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET core

Comment: look for answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254700/net-core-mvc-name-session-does-not-exist-in-current-context